# How to define vectors of complex numbers with random values of size N in C program

Tags: c

I am a beginner, how to define vectors of complex numbers with random values of size N in C program. With this code

```
complex*vector=(complex*)malloc(sizeof(complex)*N)
```

Comment: And the question is?? (as a hint `malloc()` isn't appropriate!)

Comment: Guess the homework is running late

Comment: Start by figuring out if you are writing a C program or C++ (as tag suggests)

Comment: http://instaedu.com/online-tutors/Tuhin-C-68347/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two separate problems, both of which are already answered.

How work with complex numbers: [How to work with complex numbers in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418807/how-to-work-with-complex-numbers-in-c)

How to make an array of random numbers: [To generate array of random numbers in a given range in "C"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173610/to-generate-array-of-random-numbers-in-a-given-range-in-c)

Comment: If I helped you, please reward me by marking the question answered :-)