# How to generate random numbers?

Tags: java, random, numbers

How do I write a program in java to generate random numbers between 1 and 2 ? Do I need to use for-loop or math.random ?? Is there any calculations that needs to be done before writing the code ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generating random integers in a range with Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-integers-in-a-range-with-java)

Comment: Check this link ( Generate Random Number using java)
   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-integers-in-a-range-with-java...   you can also check http://java.about.com/od/javautil/a/randomnumbers.htm

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at [java.util.Random](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html), which does much of the work for you, especially the method `nextFloat`. Since this returns `float`s between 0.0 and 1.0, just add 1 to the result to get `float`s between 1.0 and 2.0

You might also want to take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723765/generating-a-random-double-number-of-a-certain-range-in-java), which asks the same thing, just with a different range.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Random;

/** Generate 10 random integers in the range 0..99. */
public final class RandomInteger {

  public static final void main(String... aArgs){
    log("Generating 10 random integers in range 0..99.");

    //note a single Random object is reused here
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    for (int idx = 1; idx <= 10; ++idx){
      int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(100);
      log("Generated : " + randomInt);
    }

    log("Done.");
  }

  private static void log(String aMessage){
    System.out.println(aMessage);
  }
}
```