# Split value into two random numbers

Tags: java, random

I'm creating a random book catalogue in Java and I intend to split a randomly generated price value of a book package into TWO separate values (representing the individual packages for two books).

For eg. A randomly generated book package 42 costs $80 and the individual prices of the two books in that package cost $X and $Y. Here's an excerpt of my code:

```
public class MultiAgent {

int maxBookID = 50;
int maxBookPrice = 100;
int maxNumItems = 50;

void buildCatalogue() {

    int numItems = rand.nextInt(maxNumItems);
    while (bookCatalogue.size() < numItems) {
        int ranID = rand.nextInt(maxBookID);
        bookCatalogue.put(String.valueOf(ranID), rand.nextInt(maxBookPrice));

    }

    for (Object key : bookCatalogue.keySet()) {

System.out.println("Package ID: " + (String) key + "; price value: " + bookCatalogue.get(key)); //The individual values of the two books should print here
    }

}
}
```

How do I split the generated price value into two random values?

Comment: Where is `maxNumItems` defined?

Comment: I have defined that in my main class. maxNumItems = 50;

Comment: So you are taking some number, most likely greater than two, of books.  How do you end up with a pair of books?

Comment: maxNumItems is the number of book packages in the catalogue. Each of those packages have a price value which I want to split into two values to represent the individual prices for the two books that make up the total price.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generate a [random `float`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextFloat%28%29) between `0.0` and `1.0`:

```
float r = rand.nextFloat();
```

Use that to split your value:

```
float priceBook1 = packagePrice * r;
float priceBook2 = packagePrice * (1-r);
```

**Example / explanation**

Let's say `packagePrice` is `100` and `r` ends up being `0.4`:

```
priceBook1 = 100 * 0.4;      // 40
priceBook2 = 100 * (1-0.4);  // 60
```

Note, however, that one of the books could end up costing nothing (in the case of `r` being `0.0`). If you want to prevent that, just check out one of the several available questions/answers to the problem, for example [*"Generating a random double number of a certain range in Java"*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723765/generating-a-random-double-number-of-a-certain-range-in-java).

Comment: But in this case, I have bookCatalogue.get(key) representing as my randomised package price value, how do I go with that? The value is an object.

Comment: @Azaan The general strategy in this answer should work for you.  Your code isn't completely clear.

Comment: If your package price is in `bookCatalogue.get(key)`, then just replace `packagePrice` with that. As @TimBiegeleisen pointed out: I gave you somewhat of a general recipe, you should be able to adapt that to your specific case.

Comment: No worries, I got it. Thank you so much!