# Program using Multi Dimensional Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an assignment where prgram gets an integer numPoints, and doubles xlength, ylength, zlength, thenreturns 'n' random 3D data points stored in a 3D array.Where the Spatial data points should run from -xlength to +xlength, -ylength to +ylength... Im kind of confused as to what and how i am supposed to structure the program. I am using Java. Some help as to what direction I should take and tips would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[This should help you generate a random double within a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680637/how-to-generate-a-random-double-in-a-given-range).  You can take the answer there and apply it to each point you're generating.  Here's some pseudo code (this will not compile):

```
package com.sandbox;


public class Sandbox {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Double points[][][] = new Double[n][n][n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            Point point = generateRandomPointBetweenRanges(x, y, z);
            points.add(point);
        }
    }

    Point generateRandomPointBetweenRanges(double x, double y, double z) {
        xCoord = generateRandomDoubleBetweenRanges(-x, x)
        yCoord = generateRandomDoubleBetweenRanges(-y, y)
        ...
    }
}
```