# Generate a Double in the Double domain

Tags: java, random

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680637/how-to-generate-a-random-double-in-a-given-range), to create a Double number in a given range, you can use:

```
Random r = new Random();
double randomValue = rangeMin + (rangeMax - rangeMin) * r.nextDouble();
```

I'm trying to generate a double number in the double domain `[Double.MIN_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE]` using the same code mentioned above:

```
package test;

import java.util.Random;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double lower = Double.MIN_VALUE;
        double upper = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        Random   rand = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
            double a = lower + (upper - lower) * rand.nextDouble();
            System.out.println(a);
        }
    }
}
```

However, I'm getting just positive numbers even after many iterations:

```
1.436326007111308E308
2.7068601271148073E307
1.266896721067985E308
8.273233207049513E306
1.3338832492644417E308
8.584898485464862E307
1.260909190772451E308
1.5511066198317899E307
1.2083062753983258E308
2.449979496663398E307
7.333729592027637E307
7.832069948910962E307
8.493365260900201E307
5.158907971928131E307
3.126231202546818E307
1.3576316635349233E308
1.0991793636673692E308
6.991662398870649E307
```

My question is: How to generate a double number in the double range?

Comment: Read the manual:  `public static final double MIN_VALUE`
A constant holding the smallest _positive_ nonzero value of type double, 2-1074. It is equal to the hexadecimal floating-point literal 0x0.0000000000001P-1022 and also equal to Double.longBitsToDouble(0x1L).  Anyway, your code will fail when you make the minimum value very negative because... you guessed it... Java arithmetic is done in doubles and the largest double minus the negative of the largest double is more than the largest double.  It will overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The results are not what you expected, because `MIN_VALUE` is the smallest possible **positive** `double` value. The smallest possible `double` value is `-Double.MAX_VALUE` (note the minus sign).

**But** you can not simply use `lower = -Double.MAX_VALUE`, because then, the difference will not be representable as a `double`, and will overflow.

A first idea would be something like

```
double d = random.nextDouble() * Double.MAX_VALUE;
if (random.nextBoolean()) d = -d;
```

to cover the full possible range.

---

EDIT: A (possibly minor) aside: The proposed method should cover the negative `double` values as well, and should be correct in the sense that each possible value appears either in its positive or in its negative form with equal probability. However, it will not be able to return the value `Double.MAX_VALUE` (because the value returned by `Random#nextDouble()` is *strictly* smaller than 1.0). But based on the implementation of `nextDouble`, there anyhow may be `double` values that will never appear in the output.

Answer (score 0):

`Double.MIN_VALUE` is the smallest *positive* value that you can represent as a double.

it is not the largest negative number.  that would be `-Double.MAX_VALUE`

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comment and others have also said, `MIN_VALUE` is positive.  But even if you use `-Double.MAX_VALUE`, your computation will overflow double precision when computing `upper - lower` because the result will be two times the maximum double!  One way around this is:

```
val = Random.nextDouble();
return (val < 0.5) ? (-2 * val) * Double.MAX_VALUE : (2 * (val - 0.5)) * Double.MAX_VALUE;
```