# generate random objects to get spawning for java

Tags: java

I'm trying to generate a random `double` for this section of my assignment.
The question is 
"Each week, each female Guppy who is 10 weeks old or older has a 25 percent chance of spawning".

I would like to generate a random `double` to determine if each female Guppy should spawn or not.

My code so far:

```
Random r = new Random();
if (isFemale == true && getAgeInWeeks() >= 10) {
    //?
}
```

Comment: When you look at the methods on `Random`, which method do you think would be best for you to get at 25% probability? And why do you think so? *Hint: Most of the `nextXxx()` methods would be suitable.*

Comment: ya thats what i thought, but im really confused on how to input that into coding i reading up on random and next did come up but im confused

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any reason to generate a random double according to your question. What you need is an integer ranging from 0 to 3 inclusive where each number account for 25% for the spawning.

```
Random r = new Random();
if (isFemale == true && getAgeInWeeks() >= 10) {
    // Generate a random integer in [0,3]
    // Since there is a 25% or 1/4 chance 
    if(Math.abs(r.nextInt()) % 4 == 1){
       //Note that the 1 in the condition can be replaced by any 
       // integer in [0,3]
       //Put spawning code here 
    }
}
```

Check out this link for more information on random:
[Random (Java Platform SE 7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html)

Comment: Use `nextInt(4)` instead of `nextInt()` with the modulo operator.  The former is correctly random, but the latter is not if Integer.MAX_VALUE is not a multiple of your maximum value.

Answer (score 1):

To generate a random `double`, you can look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680637/generate-a-random-double-in-a-range), however, this problem can more easily be solved by generating random `int`s.

In your situation, generating an `int` between `0` to `3` is what you want because checking if it is `0` will be true 25% of the time (1 Value / 4 Possible values = 25%).

**EDIT:** If you would like to also generate a random number to see how many spawn a Guppy will have use `threadLocalRandomInstance.nextInt(int bound);` like before.

These constraints can be translated to code like this:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        ThreadLocalRandom tlr = ThreadLocalRandom.current();

        int num = tlr.nextInt(3 + 1); //Bound is exclusive so add 1.
        int spawn;

        if(num == 0) {
            spawn = tlr.nextInt(100 + 1); //Again, bound is exclusive so add 1.
        } else spawn = 0;

        System.out.println("This guppy had " + spawn + " spawn.");
    }
}
```

I use [`ThreadLocalRandom`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html) as it is more straightforward as supported by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/363692/4475997).
If you are not using Java 1.7+, use [`Random#nextInt(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-) instead as also shown by [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/363692/4475997).

Comment: basically say 0 to 100 babies with each spawn