# How to specify a maximum value in Java's SecureRandom nextLong

Tags: java, random

In Java I wish to generate a randomly picked long number within an exclusive upper bound.

Normally if it were an `Int` I could do

```
int nextInt = new SecureRandom.nextInt(500);
```

Why can't I also do

```
long nextLong = new SecureRandom.nextLong(4294967296L);
```

Is there a work around to this?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: random long number in 0 <= x < n range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546078/java-random-long-number-in-0-x-n-range)

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44278281/why-there-is-no-nextdouble-nextfloat-and-nextlong-which-accept-a-bound-in

Comment: The accepted answer of the dupe question won't work, but the second answer ([Java: random long number in 0 <= x < n range](//stackoverflow.com/a/2546158)).

Comment: Thanks for all your inputs. However, I am more interested in a Cryptographically secured approach. I think `ThreadLocalRandom` isn't cryptographically secured. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: That's why I said you should use the other answer (the one I've linked). That uses `Random`, but would work with `SecureRandom` as well.

Comment: @Tom as the comments say, that version is not uniform distributed. If you want Secure you definitly want uniform.

Comment: Probably, as workaround you can use `SecureRandom.longs` method introduced in Java 8. I added more details in the answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Probably, as workaround you can use [`longs`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#longs-long-long-long-) method introduced in Java 8. So, if you need to get `SecureRandom` long value in the range `[minLong, maxLong]`, one approach would be:

```
long minLong = -1L;
long maxLong = 4294967296L;

long boundedLong = 
     new SecureRandom()
        .longs(minLong, maxLong + 1)
        .findFirst()
        .getAsLong();
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be a `SecureRandom`?

If not, then you have two easy options, using `nextLong​(long bound)` of [`SplittableRandom`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SplittableRandom.html#nextLong(long)) or [`ThreadLocalRandom`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html#nextLong(long)):

```
long nextLong = new SplittableRandom().nextLong(4294967296L);

long nextLong = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(4294967296L);
```

---

**UPDATE**

If it has to be `SecureRandom`, you can always copy the code of those two methods, which are implemented the same (below copied from Java 11):

```
public static long nextLong(SecureRandom random, long bound) {
    if (bound <= 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(BadBound);
    long r = random.nextLong();
    long m = bound - 1;
    if ((bound & m) == 0L) // power of two
        r &= m;
    else { // reject over-represented candidates
        for (long u = r >>> 1;
             u + m - (r = u % bound) < 0L;
             u = random.nextLong() >>> 1)
            ;
    }
    return r;
}
```

That should answer the question *"Is there a work around to this?"*, since writing your own code is a valid workaround.

Comment: Why to bother copying method implementations if `SecureRandom` API already has bonded versions like [`longs`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#longs-long-long-long-) ? See [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58123495/how-to-specify-a-maximum-value-in-javas-securerandom-nextlong/58123834#58123834) below for more details.

Comment: @Zgurskyi Because you had already given that answer, so I'm providing an alternative to using streams.