# How to round to 1 decimal place using Java

Tags: java

I am trying to round to the nearest decimal value, however, this line of code keeps returning a number between 0 and 1, I also want the output to be between 1 and 10. Where am I going wrong?

```
power[i] = rng.nextDouble();
```

Comment: I @Anton, please post more code; in this way we can understand better your problem

Comment: Please read the documentation of the `nextDouble` method. It probably states that it returns a random number between `0` (inclusive) and `1` (exclusive). Why do you expect something different? Please do some research before posting a question on StackOverflow, this is an actual requirement (see [ask]). There are many questions such as [How to generate random integers within a specific range in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/how-to-generate-random-integers-within-a-specific-range-in-java)

Comment: I think [Generate a random double in range](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3680648/4417306) is just what you need.

Answer (score -1):

You can use JDK's [`Math.round`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round(double)).

A detailed example can be found [here](https://way2java.com/java-lang/class-math-java-lang/java-math-round-function-round-up-round-down-value/).

Comment: This answer is more suited as **comment**. Please do not abuse the answering system for incomplete answers. See [answer], thanks.

Answer (score -1):

`Math.round(ThreadLocalRandom.nextDouble(1,10)*10)/10.0`